# Pure CSS Menu not on side on the top

Tags: html, css, menu

I am having trouble getting my Pure CSS styling to work so that I can create a Menu on the left side of my webpage. This is what I get when I open the file. I am using Flask also just in case that is relevant.

This is what my site looks like:[image: My Site (in Firefox Quantum 61.0.1)]

And this is the code that I am using to create this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- Check Compattibility with Pure CSS -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Check Compattibility with Pure CSS -->

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- Check Compattibility with Pure CSS -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->

        <title>Home</title>

    </head>
<style>
.custom-restricted-width {
    /* To limit the menu width to the content of the menu: */
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* Or set the width explicitly: */
    width: 10em; 
}
</style>
<div class="pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
    <!-- <a href="#" class="pure-menu-link pure-menu-heading">Home</a> -->
    <span class="pure-menu-heading">My Site</span>

    <ul class="pure-menu-list">
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="newuser/register" class="pure-menu-link">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<body bgcolor="black" text="white">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pure-u-24-24">
            <img src="/static/images/Logo.png" class="pure-img" />
            <h1>Welcome Home</h1><br><br><br>
            <p>Please continue to check back for updates!</p><br><br>
            <p>More comming soon...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am new to Pure CSS and I am trying to create an elegant menu that is on the side of the page similar to what you will find on the Menu Page on their website: https://purecss.io/menus/

Answer (score 0):

First of all your menu needs to be within the `<body></body>` tags. See it here:

```
<body bgcolor="black" text="white">
    <div class="pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
        <span class="pure-menu-heading">My Site</span>
        <ul class="pure-menu-list">
            <li class="pure-menu-item">
                <a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item">
                <a href="newuser/register" class="pure-menu- 
                    link">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pure-u-24-24">
            <img src="/static/images/Logo.png" class="pure-img" />
            <h1>Welcome Home</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Please continue to check back for updates!</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>More comming soon...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

To create a similar sidebar menu as PureCSS has just add the following:

```
.custom-restricted-width {
    width: 10em;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #191818;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

and for the container you can add:

```
.container {
    padding-left: 15em;
 }
```

Here's the full code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Check Compattibility with Pure CSS -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Check Compattibility with Pure CSS -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Check Compattibility with Pure CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    .pure-menu {
        width: 10em;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9;
        bottom: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        background: #191818;
        overflow-y: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

    .container {
        padding-left: 15em;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="pure-menu custom-restricted-width">
        <!-- <a href="#" class="pure-menu-link pure-menu-heading">Home</a> -->
        <span class="pure-menu-heading">My Site</span>
        <ul class="pure-menu-list">
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="newuser/register" class="pure-menu-link">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pure-u-24-24">
            <img src="/static/images/Logo.png" class="pure-img" />
            <h1>Welcome Home</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>Please continue to check back for updates!</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p>More comming soon...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I am a bit confused why would I need to define the .pure-menu I thought that would be something that was contained in the style sheet that is called at the top.

Also just a question and a point of being particular. It seems that your full code example is missing the top two lines of code: 
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>

Comment: Hi Ben, the `.pure-menu` class was just to overwrite the current styling of the menu with the new requested one by you. So you could get rid of the `.custom-restricted-width` class. You could have called the class anything and added the styling based on that class. 

You are absolutely right that I'm missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top to make sure newer browsers render the content correctly.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. I see that `.pure-menu` as you defined it will overwrite the class. I just was under the impression that PureCSS had these types of styling built into it and that was why I was calling `class="pure-menu"` in the first place.

Comment: It will not specifically overwrite the whole class. Only the declarations that are already defined for the `.pure-menu` class from their library. So let's say they already defined a `width: 35em`, but you want a `width: 15em` - then you keep overwrite the current define width instead of declaring a whole new class.